# Code Generation of an Upsert / Merge for SQL Server - C#/.NET

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, code-generation, upsert

What is the best way to generate an "UPSERT" Merge statement for SQL Server? I'm looking for a way to just put in a SQL Server connection string and then point a piece of code at a single SQL Server table.

Is it to crawl INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES for the metadata and write a small console app? other suggestions?

I'd like to be able to copy and paste the resulting code into a "const string sql" variable to then use with something like Dapper.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=sql+server+merge+generator Stack Overflow is not suitable to ask to find tools or websites.

Comment: Just wondered in addition to how to approach it... if I was solving a known issue? Also, wondering if someone has already solved this with T4 or CodeSmith?

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue and your question is good and important. It's just that SO is not a good place to ask. It is specifically forbidden and for a good reason (see the FAQ and meta). Ask elsewhere. (You're welcome here, of course. Just not with that question.)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to upsert in SQL Server in C# is to bulk insert into a temp table and issue a merge from there to the production table.

```
var tmpTable =
                "create table #myTable (a int, b nvarchar(200))";

var conString = "my_connection_string";

 using (var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                con.Open();

                //Create Temp Table
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(tmpTable, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //Build Data Set
                var dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("A", typeof(int)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("B", typeof(string)));

                foreach (var myDataRow in myData)
                {
                    var row = dt.NewRow();

                    row["A"] = myDataRow.A;
                    row["B"] = myDataRow.B;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                //Write to temp table
                using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    bulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                    bulk.DestinationTableName = "#myTable";
                    bulk.WriteToServer(dt);
                }

                //Do the upsert
                var mergeSql = "merge into myData as Target " +
                               "using #myTable as Source " +
                               "on " +
                               "Target.A=Source.A " +
                               "and Target.B = Source.B " +
                               "when matched then " +
                               "update set Target.A=Source.A, Target.B = Source.B, " +
                               "when not matched then " +
                               "insert (A,B) values (Source.A,Source.B);";

                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.CommandText = mergeSql;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //Clean up the temp table
                cmd.CommandText = "drop table #myTable";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

I've tested several ways and this is the fastest I have came across. I use it in a production environment for inserting millions of rows daily without issue.

Comment: Looks like your blog hosting expired. Do you still have information on how to do this?

Comment: Yeah killed it. The answer is to do a bulk insert into a temp table. Then do a sql merge. So much faster, like over 50% faster.

Comment: I updated my answer. Removed the link to the site since I no longer have it online, and posted the answer directly here.